# Can't get Powershell to pull $StrComputer.name

Tags: arrays, powershell, attributes

I'm writing a script to have Powershell query a PC for a folder and then enter some text in an Excel spreadsheet if the folder exists. Everything is working except I can't get the $path variable to pull the name attribute from the $StrComputer variable.

```
$HELLO = Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot "%OU%" -LdapFilter "(Name=COMPUTERNAME)" -IncludedProperties pwdLastSet -SizeLimit 0 | select-object name, pwdLastSet, SamAccountName, lastLogonTimestamp

foreach ($strComputer in $HELLO)
{
$path = null
$path = "\\$strComputer.name\c$\Program Files\folder"
    If((Test-Path -Path $path) -eq $true) 
        { 
        $c.Cells.Item($intRow, 15) = ("folder")
        }
}
```

When I toggle breakpoint on "If((Test-Path -Path $path) -eq $true)" and hover over $path I'm getting the full array returned: $path = \(@{name=COMPUTERNAME; pwdLastSet=01/31/2014 11:09:20; SamAccountName=COMPUTERNAME$; lastLogonTimestamp=}.name)\c$\Program Files\Folder

How do I get this to pull the name attribute from the array and insert in properly to get $path = \COMPUTERNAME\c$\Program Files\Folder?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this $strComputer.name

To this $($strComputer.name)

When you encase a variable in double quotes, it won't pick up the property to swap it out unless you surround it with $().

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. This site rocks!